# Counting the word per sentence in python

Tags: python

I am having a problem to count the word per sentence. I only get the count of all words from the inputted sentence.

```
sen = input("Enter atleast 5 sentences.\nRemember to end the sentence with period\nSentence: ")
word_list = sen.split()
num_word = len(word_list)
print("Total words of the sentence: ", num_word)
```

My ideal output is to show the counted word per sentence and the average word usage of the sentences.

For example:

**Sentence:** Hello World! I love programming.

I want to show the count per sentence like: 2 + 3

Average: 5 / 2 = 2 since decimal is not accepted.

I don't want it to be straight into the computation because I wanna know how many words are used per sentence.

Comment: You should probably split `sen` by sentence terminators to get a list of sentences

Answer (score 0):

**LOGIC** :

First, you may need a regex to split your string into sentences.

```
import re

s = """Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."""
m = re.split(r'(?<=[^A-Z].[.?]) +(?=[A-Z])', s)
```

Then, you can split them, counting the words.

```
for i in m:
    word_list = i.split()
    num_word = len(word_list)
    print(i)
    print("Total words of the sentence: ", num_word)
```

Output:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Total words of the sentence:  12
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
Total words of the sentence:  31
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
Total words of the sentence:  17
It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Total words of the sentence:  31
```

It's now easy to calculate the mean value.

```
total_words = len(s.split())
sentences_count = len(m)
average_words = total_words // sentences_count
print(f'The average number of words per sentence is: ', average_words)
```

Output:

```
The average number of words per sentence is:  22
```

---

**COMPLETE CODE** :

```
import re

s = """Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."""
m = re.split(r'(?<=[^A-Z].[.?]) +(?=[A-Z])', s)
total_words = len(s.split())
sentences_count = len(m)
average_words = total_words // sentences_count
for i in m:
    word_list = i.split()
    num_word = len(word_list)
    print(i)
    print("Total words of the sentence: ", num_word)

print(f'The average number of words per sentence is: ', average_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't totally robust but demonstrates an approach that you could use:-

```
import re
# Assume that sentences are terminated by either period, question mark or exclamation mark
sentence = 'Hello world! How are you today?'
s = re.split('[\?!\.]', sentence)[:-1]
ns = len(s)
print(f'There are {ns} sentences in the string')
total = len(sentence.split())
average = total // ns
print(f'The average number of words per sentence is {average}')
```

Comment: Can I get the word per sentence? How to do it? For example, the first sentence there will be an output of 2, then for the 2nd, it is 3, before getting the average?

Comment: Yes you can. Use *split()*

Comment: There's a split in your code, but it only output the whole count of word in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

First, split the sentences by sentence terminators. Use re.split and a regex to split by multiple characters. Also remove all sentences of length zero.:

```py
import re
sentences = re.split("\.|\!|\?|\n", sen)
sentences = [i for i in sentences if len(i) > 0]
```

Now split each sentence into words and output the results:

```py
words = [sentence.split() for sentence in sentences]
wpersen = [len(i) for i in words]
print(f"Length of sentences: {wpersen}\nMean: {sum(wpersen) // len(wpersen)}")
```

Finished code:

```py
import re
sen = input("Enter atleast 5 sentences.\nRemember to end the sentence with period\nSentence: ")
sentences = re.split("\.|\!|\?|\n", sen)
sentences = [i for i in sentences if len(i) > 0]
words = [sentence.split() for sentence in sentences]
wpersen = [len(i) for i in words]
print(f"Length of sentences: {wpersen}\nMean: {sum(wpersen) // len(wpersen)}")
```